# Given a vector $u$ such that $\langle v,u\rangle=0$ for every vector $v$, prove that $u=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Suppose $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle $  is an inner product on  $\mathbb{F}^n$.
>   Given a vector $u$ such that $\langle v,u\rangle=0$ for every vector $v$, prove that $u=0$.

Here $\mathbb F$ is a field. Trying to figure out how to approach this, although I am sure I am missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

What happens if $u=v$?

Since $\langle u,u\rangle=0$, the vector $u$ is zero, because  $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is an inner product.

Comment: Like I thought, Im stupid :) This helped. Thanks!

Comment: And just in case someone else comes across this: this means <u,u>=0, which in turn means u=0.

Comment: I changed $<\cdot,\cdot>$ to $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$